# ObfuscationAttribute class not found?

Tags: .net, windows-store-apps, obfuscation, eazfuscator

I want to exclude renaming files of Windows store class library. Found bellow attributes needs to be set but I don't find ObfuscationAttribute class in System.Reflection namespace? What is the Store equivalent? How can I stop this happening in EazFuscator.Net?

```
[System.Reflection.ObfuscationAttribute(Feature = "properties renaming")]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent in the available API's for Windows Store Apps. Take a look at [the official API listings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441595.aspx). You'll have to do your configuration in whatever 3rd party tool you are using.

Comment: Any idea, How can I set configure this in Eazfuscator.NET?

Comment: Contact their support - support@gapotchenko.com and post the results back here if they can help you :)

Comment: Response from suppot : "The Obfuscation attribute is not defined in WinRT. Please add a ready-to-use source file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Eazfuscator.NET\Code Snippets\C#\ObfuscationAttributes.cs" to your project. Once added, the ObfuscationAttribute will appear."